# Weird "NoViableAltException" in Tree grammar with imaginary token

Tags: tree, antlr, antlr3, tree-grammar

I can not understand a "NoViableAltException"exception when I compile my Tree grammar.

Here's a little piece of my grammar with the rule that gives me problems:

```
keyword_controls_sub
    : expression (MB_COMA expression)* -> ^(MATCH_STATEMENT expression)+
    ;
```

Which generates a tree like:

```
                       +-----------------+
                       |                 |
                       |      ROOT       |
                       |                 |
                       +-----------------+
                               |
                               |
             +-------------------------------------+
             |                 |                   |
   +------------------+  +-----------------+ +-----------------+
   |                  |  |                 | |                 |
   | MATCH_STATEMENT  |  | MATCH_STATEMENT | | MATCH_STATEMENT |
   |                  |  |                 | |                 |
   +------------------+  +-----------------+ +-----------------+
            |                     |                   |
  +-------------------+  +-----------------+ +-----------------+
  |                   |  |                 | |                 |
  |    expression     |  |   expression    | |   expression    |
  |                   |  |                 | |                 |
  +-------------------+  +-----------------+ +-----------------+
```

And the rule in my TreeGrammar that causes the exception:

```
keyword_controls_sub
    : ^(MATCH_STATEMENT expression)+
    ;
```

Specifically, the ANTLR compiler returns the following errors:

```
error 100: syntax error: antlr: NoViableAltException(79@[])
error 100: syntax error: assign.types: NoViableAltException(0@[])
node from line 2482:10 no viable alternative at input '+'
error 100: syntax error: buildnfa: NoViableAltException(0@[])
error 100: syntax error: codegen: NoViableAltException(0@[])
error 100: syntax error: antlr.print: NoViableAltException(0@[])
error 100: syntax error: antlr.print: NoViableAltException(0@[])
```

If I change the tree grammar to:

```
keyword_controls_sub
: ^(MATCH_STATEMENT expression+)
;
```

There are no compiler errors, but I think that it is not correct, since in this case there would only be one MATCH_STATEMENT block.

Note: I'm using ANTLR3 C Runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the root operator can be applied to a block. It actually only makes sense for single token, as it marks this token as the root of a tree. Also, why do you want to duplicate the MATCH_STATEMENT virtual token multiple times? That's totally redundant. You could easily write:

```
keyword_controls_sub:
    MATCH_STATEMENT^ expression+
;
```

and get all expressions as children under a single MATCH_STATEMENT root node.

And a side note: there is now a C++ target for ANTLR4. ANTLR3 is quite outdated, so maybe you should consider upgrading.

Comment: There's two ways to write tree rewrites in ANTLR 3 - the `^(node1 ...)` syntax means the first node in the parentheses is the parent and all others are its children. It can even be nested like `^(level1 ^(level2 level3 level3) level2)`. Is that what you're wondering about?

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the code for `keyword_controls_sub` has no rewrite operator, hence ^(...) is acting like a block. Not sure if that is even valid ANTLR syntax.

Comment: I've never used tree grammars, so I can only guess based on rewrite rules syntax. Maybe OP tried to use rewrite but got the syntax wrong and ANTLR interprets it as root operator?

Comment: Thank you @MikeLischke!! Regarding your comment _"... get all expressions as children under a single MATCH_STATEMENT root node"_, is exactly what I have done and works correctly. But I still think the syntax `^(MATCH_STATEMENT expression+)` should be correct too. 
As for the new C++ runtime in ANTLR4, I am aware of it but it is very recent and I would rather wait a bit before doing the migration.